# Match and replace digits with sed in specific lines

Tags: bash, replace, sed, awk, pattern-matching

Using the Ubuntu 12.04 and vim 2.22.0, inside the vim editor I shall use:

```
:9;13;17;21s/\d\+/1/
```

to match digits before ^M (and sometime just digits without any tails) and change them to 1. This pattern occurs only in the beginning of the line #9,13,17 and 21. i.e:

```
vi _ccc_info_datasets:

...
=====
2
../../automotive_susan_data/2.pgm output_large.corners.pgm -c > ftmp_out
691^M  // ---------> change to 1^M
=====
...
```

As I have understood, the same can't go  with sed as like :

```
find . type f  -name "_ccc_info_datasets" -exec sed -i '9;13;17;21s/\d\+/1/' {} \;
```

for changing several files in bash. I have tried :

```
find . type f  -name "_ccc_info_datasets" -exec sed -i '9;13;17;21s/[0-9]{1;\}/1/' {} \;
```

but it executes with no errors but no results. Any helps is appreciated ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use sed like that. You need to use multiple sed replacements with `-e` switch like this:

```
sed -i.bak -e '9s/[0-9][0-9]*\('$'\r''\)/1\1/' -e '13s/[0-9][0-9]*\('$'\r''\)/1\1/' \
    -e '17s/[0-9][0-9]*\('$'\r''\)/1\1/' -e '21s/[0-9][0-9]*\('$'\r''\)/1\1/' file
```

**Update: Though awk doesn't support inline editing I believe using awk will be much cleaner for this task.**  Consider below awk command:

```
awk 'NR ~ /^9|13|17|21$/{sub(/[0-9]+\r$/, "1\r")}1' file > _temp && mv _temp file
```

Comment: tnx @anubhava for the answer. However, by executing these sed -e I am loosing the tail end "^M" character after the digits and secondly since it won't be inline (sed -i), I am receiving the output on the screen instead of being save inside the file.

Comment: You can insert `-i` above and it won't delete `^M` since I am capturing it in `\1` and using it in replacement string: `1\1`

Comment: tnx @anubhava, this is worlking! ;)

Comment: Glad to know its workig. If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.